# Create resource from existing .ico icon

Tags: visual-c++, wxwidgets, embedded-resource, .ico

I have an icon in .ico format. I want to add it as a resource in my VC++ project. I want to set it as the main icon using wxWidgets.

I right click resources, and my choices are existing item and new item. If I select new item and .ico, it brings up a bitmap editor. That can't be right. So I select "existing item" and put foo.ico into the resources.  But the following fails:

wxFrame::SetIcon(wxICON(foo));

I have tried various decorations, like foo.ico and  wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICO_RESOURCE, yada yada, but I have yet to strike the perfect combination.

Edit: I found something on the net that says I need to create a new resource and add the foo.ico to that. I tried following the instructions, but no joy.

Comment: A while ago, I used a resource icon for the exe file and used the way you have mentioned in the edit part and then relied on Visual Studio's resource compiler to do the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it, but there must be a better way.

I copied a resource file, namely sample.rc, from the wxWidgets samples. I edited it in a text editor, replacing the icon name with foo.ico in a couple of places. I also commented-out an #include that referred to a wxWidget project directory. In Visual Studio, I added that file to the resources. In the MyFrame constructor in my program, I wrote,

```
SetIcon(wxICON(sample));
```

Very hackish, but it worked.

Comment: Not hackish. Resource file .rc is the easiest way of providing icons amd other resources to your Windows project, and letting them be in the executable.

Comment: @Ripi2 Editing an existing .rc in a text editor seemed hackish to me. Presumably there is a way to create and populate a new one in in Visual Studio, but the maze of menus and options is too treacherous for me.

Comment: You should be able to add the icon using the IDE if you prefer (also I admit I don't see the point), but you should _not_ remove the inclusion of `wx/msw/wx.rc`, it is needed and miscellaneous random things risk breaking if you don't include the resources defined in it.